# Degeneracy of Rotational Energy Levels of a Diatomic Molecule

Tags: quantum-mechanics, rotational-dynamics

To derive the energy levels of a diatomic molecule (with the z axis the axis of symmetry of the molecule), we write the Hamiltonian as $$H=\frac{1}{2}(\frac{L_x^2}{I}+\frac{L_y^2}{I}+\frac{L_z^2}{I_z})$$ or alternatively as $$H=\frac{1}{2}[\frac{L^2}{I}+L_z^2(\frac{1}{I_z}-\frac{1}{I})]$$ Now we know that there are mutual eigenstates $|l,m\rangle$ such that $L^2|l,m\rangle=l(l+1)\hbar^2|l,m\rangle$ and $L_z|l,m\rangle=m\hbar|l,m\rangle$ for integer $m$,$l$ and so clearly the states $|l,m\rangle$ are eigenstates of the Hamiltonian with eigenvalues, and so rotational energy levels given by $$E_l=\frac{\hbar^2}{2}[\frac{l(l+1)}{I}+m^2(\frac{1}{I_z}-\frac{1}{I})]$$ Now the general argument seems to be that $I_z$ is very small and so we must have $m=0$ otherwise the energy will be inconcievably large, thus $$E_l=\frac{\hbar^2l(l+1)}{2I}$$

So this seems to say that such a molecule always has to be in a state of the form $|l,0\rangle$ regardless of $l$. However, on many occasions when considering these energy levels, it states that the degeneracy of a given $l$ state is $2l+1$ - but we have restricted $m=0$ so surely all of the degeneracies should be unity?

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotational_spectroscopy#Rotational_line_intensities, where this degeneracy is partly used to explain the intensity.